# Плагин для wordpress как отдельная страница со своим лэйаутом

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте!

Есть сайт на WP, к которому мне нужно написать плагин. Задача следующая:

1. Есть раздел меню, в котором есть свое подменю, т.е. двухуровневый dropdown, и второй уровень нужно выводить динамически из базы.
2. Информация из базы данных по ссылкам вышеуказанного меню должна выводиться на отдельной странице со своим лэйаутом. То есть приблизительно так: я клацаю ссылку, данные передаются в POST или парсится URL и данная страница выводит динамический контент.

Вопрос: как реализовать данный функционал с помощью плагина, чтобы можно было вписаться в оформление существующего сайта? Возможно ли такое для WP в принципе?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если нет необходимости оформлять это именно в форме плагина, то сделать это можно так:

1. Создайте в папке шаблона PHP-файл с произвольным именем и необходимым вам функционалом. Например,

   ```
   <?php
       /* Template Name: Hello-Tpl */   // этот комментарий позволяет увидеть файл в списке шаблонов для страницы
       get_header();   // для работы в шаблоне сайта

       echo 'Hello world!'; // ваш функционал

       get_footer(); // для работы в шаблоне сайта
   ?>
   ```
2. Создайте новую страницу, выбрав в блоке "Атрибуты->Шаблон" название вашего шаблона (первая строка комментария): "Hello-Tpl"